# How to publish Windows Form Application with Entity Framework

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, publishing

Hi All I have created a windows form application using VS 2010, Entity Framework and MYSQL database. Database is hosted at some hosting company and is accessible from every where. Now when I create an step up of my application and install on other systems it stops working. No error message nothing. Please help if anyone have build windows form application with entity framework and successfully installed on other machines.

Tried so much on google but no luck.

Comment: Do you do any logging? This always helps to find problems. For example, you can write log messages to the windows event system.

Comment: Do you have mysql ado.net provider on the other system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All I have found solution. The problem is with use of MYSQL database in my application. I have used MYSQL connector and it is causing the problem. I simply install MYSQL connector to remote machines and it solves the problem.